# What is this creature I found on my house?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What is this creature and what species is this?

I found this on my balcony.

[image]

Comment: It's a caterpillar but please add your approximate location, it helps a lot the id.

Answer (score 22):

Well, your question ended up being closed... If I understand it correctly, you simply asked *"what is this creature?"* and, after that, you asked *"what species is this?"*. That being the case, the question seems to be clear enough to me.

Therefore, let's see:

#### What is this creature?

It's a caterpillar of a moth from the Genus [*Orgyia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgyia).

#### What species is this?

The Wikipedia link above lists more than 40 species. Here is, for instance, *Orgyia antiqua*:

[image]

And *Orgyia leucostigma*:

[image]

But my guess is that your specimen is *Orgyia australis* (specially if you live here down under):

[image]

Adding your location will greatly improve the chances of defining the species inside that genus.

#### Conclusion

That's simply a caterpillar (larva) of a moth from the Genus *Orgyia*. Narrowing it down to the species depends on you adding more information to the question, specially geographic location.

Comment: Based on his name I would hazard a guess he's from India. There are Orgyia australis in India, particularly around crop fields.

Comment: @JohnBell Don't forget the other Indian *Orgyia* not yet described.

Comment: And that not every Indian person *gasp* lives in India...but good job, everybody, on the quick ID. Distinctive little guys. It's usually O. leucostigma here in south Texas, I think.